# Sort large SQL database of Electrical Meter Readings through PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure how to ask this properly as I'm a little green to this and seeing how I can't ask it properly I haven't been able to google the results.

Backstory: I manage an apartment complex. Every apartment has a digital electrical meter. Every day I can download a CSV file of all unit's and their readings.

Using PHP and SQL i can pull the UNIT # from a table called tenants - Then I can reference the specific unit # in a search on my browser from a specific date and it will automatically calculate the usage for the month (or whatever range I select).

I have that part down! What I'm trying to do now is create a one button pull where I can see all usage from all tenants in one easy table.

Right now the database looks likes this

```
|UNIT|KWH|DATE      |
|101 |100|01/01/2022|
|102 |80 |01/01/2022|
|103 |110|01/01/2022|
|104 |108|01/01/2022|
|101 |110|01/02/2022|
|102 |90 |01/02/2022|
|103 |125|01/02/2022|
|104 |128|01/01/2022|
ETC
```

It just keeps growing as I import the CSV file daily into the database

What I want to be able to quickly see is:

```
|UNIT|TOTAL KWH|DATE RANGE     
|101 |10       |01/01/2022 - 01/30/2022|
|102 |10       |01/01/2022 - 01/30/2022|
|103 |15       |01/01/2022 - 01/30/2022|
|104 |20       |01/01/2022 - 01/30/2022|
```

The below code gives me the specific unit

```
SELECT Max(KWH)-Min(KWH) AS TOTALKWH,UNIT AS UNIT 
FROM testdb 
WHERE UNIT = 'Unit_220' 
AND Date >='11/01/2022' AND Date <='11/30/2022'
```

I'm stuck on how to select all units and not just a specific unit. Any thoughts how to do this easily? Or perhaps a better way than I am currently?

Comment: Removing the Unit number from your where clause.

Comment: Please dont spam TAGS, are you using MySQL or SQLServer. They are not at all the same beast

Comment: Removing the Unit number from where clause only displays one unit the top. Not all of them. I'm wondering how to display all of them. 

Yes my date column is text and not a date type. The CSV file displays date in the front format and when it auto inserts into database it doesn't insert as date correctly.

Comment: Your date column would appear to be a text type column and not a Date type. The American date format is of not use to anything that involves logic. Store is as a DATE type and if you want to present it as the USA format do that in the presentation layer

Comment: Why would you take the SQL out of tags? It's more an SQL question than PHP at this point.

Comment: _NOTE_ The UNIT appears to be numbers like `102` not `Unit_220` so `WHERE UNIT = 'Unit_220'` is wrong

Comment: THE 102 was a demo of what i'm after not an exact replica . The CSV auto names the units. So Unit_220 is correct and it does display the correct result for Unit_220. I'm looking to have all units displayed in one table if that makes sense

Comment: Because you  quoted 2 incompatible DBMS's, add back the one you are actually using

Comment: ___I'm stuck on how to select all units___ If you want all the units then remove the filter `UNIT = 'Unit_220'` of course

Comment: Removing the filter only displays the top UNIT in the database. Not all of them.

Comment: And if you want the TOTAL UINTS for a Month then you want to use `SUM()` there is no logic in finding the MAX minus the MIN over a month

Comment: You are misunderstanding what it's doing. Everyday the meter goes up as usage goes up. I'm not looking for the sum. I want to bill the tenant for his usage for the month. I want a script that calculates the usage on the 1st of the month compared to the end of the month. HENCE the min max. That script works perfect and I can do it just fine. I'm wondering if there is a way to display all units. That's all i'm after.

Comment: So remove `UNIT = 'Unit_220' AND` so your where clause is just `WHERE Date >='11/01/2022' AND Date <='11/30/2022'`

Comment: And add `GROUP BY USINT`

Comment: That does not work - I have tried that. A few times. It just displays 1 unit. Not all of them. I think you are right using the 'group by' function. I'm just not sure what to do. GROUP BY UNIT does not work.

Comment: SELECT Max(KWH)-Min(KWH) AS TOTALKWH,UNIT AS UNIT FROM testdb WHERE AND Date >='11/01/2022' AND Date <='11/30/2022' GROUP BY UNIT
Gave me an error.

Comment: You were right!

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL to achieve your desired idea.

```
SELECT
    tb1.UNIT,
    (
        tb1.KWH -
        (
        SELECT
            tb3.KWH
        FROM
            kwh AS tb3
        WHERE
            tb3.DATE = DATE_ADD(tb1.DATE, INTERVAL -1 MONTH) AND tb3.UNIT = tb1.UNIT
        )
    ) AS "TOTAL KWH",
    CONCAT(
        DATE_ADD(tb1.DATE, INTERVAL -1 MONTH),
        " ~ ",
        DATE_ADD(tb1.DATE, INTERVAL -1 DAY)
    ) AS "DATE RANGE"
FROM
    kwh AS tb1
WHERE
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT(tb2.DATE)
    FROM
        kwh AS tb2
    WHERE
        tb2.DATE < tb1.DATE
    ) >= 1
ORDER BY
    tb1.DATE;
```